# R - Sequences of repeated events calculation (iteration)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence, tidyverse

I'm dealing with a large dataset for which I'm trying to calculate the duration of sessions with repeated events. During the process of data collection one session is composed of events in the same position with the same IDs (A,B,C) in interval of 10 seconds. How should I code to calculate session length that is the difference between first event and last event? In this case, the duration is actually the last event if Second is sorted in ascending order, and I would need to add an additional 10 seconds to account for the time before the next event.

```
For ex: Session A, duration = 50 + 10 = 60
        Session A, duration = 20 + 10 = 30
        Session B, duration = 30 + 10 = 40
        Session C, duration = 50 + 10 = 60
```

I'm think using function last() then add 10 to the last record of each session can be the process, but since each session have different amount of events, I'm having trouble to figure out an iteration/code for the entire dataset.

```
 Session_ID         Second           Position
 A                    10                 1
 A                    20                 1
 A                    30                 1 
 A                    40                 1
 A                    50                 1
 A                    10                 2
 A                    20                 2
 B                    10                 1
 B                    20                 1
 B                    30                 1
 C                    10                 3
 C                    20                 3
 C                    30                 3
 C                    40                 3
 C                    50                 3
            .
            .
            .
```

Result:

```
Session              Duration      Position
 A                     60              1
 A                     30              2
 B                     40              1
 C                     60              3
             .
             .
             .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Session_ID, Position) %>% 
  filter(Second == max(Second)) %>% 
  mutate(Second = Second + 10)
```

Alternatively, if your `Second` is ordered, you can `slice` the last row of each group:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Session_ID, Position) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  mutate(Second = Second + 10)
```

Both solutions return:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Session_ID, Position [4]
  Session_ID Second Position
  <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
1 A            60.0        1
2 A            30.0        2
3 B            40.0        1
4 C            60.0        3
```

But I would stick with the first since you won't have to worry about the order of `Second`.

Data:

```
text <- "Session_ID         Second           Position
        A                    10                 1
        A                    20                 1
        A                    30                 1 
        A                    40                 1
        A                    50                 1
        A                    10                 2
        A                    20                 2
        B                    10                 1
        B                    20                 1
        B                    30                 1
        C                    10                 3
        C                    20                 3
        C                    30                 3
        C                    40                 3
        C                    50                 3"

df <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: could you explain how slice(n()) selects the max Second in each session?

Comment: Slice(n()) is just selecting the last row (per group in this case). And this is working because your data is sorted in ascending order. If you want it to be more robust, and extract the max value per group without it being in order, I can update my answer. Won’t be able to do it till later though.

Comment: Thank you! Could you update the code to consider if there is no order? This will be very useful! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Of course! Won’t be able to get to it right now, but will once I’m home

Comment: I can wait, not a problem at all. Thanks!